# Menu not create in Android

Tags: android

Menu not create ... What is wrong with the code ? 
What is the reason ?

```
 public class myListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        ArrayList<Country> countries;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                countries = new ArrayList<Country>();


            myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this,countries);
            ListView listView = new ListView(this);
            registerForContextMenu(listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            setContentView(listView);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
            return true;

        }

    }
```

// XML file ..............
    //--------------------options.xml------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/open_item_menu"
        android:title="Open" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_item_menu"
        android:title="close" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Plz post the code of R.menu.options file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/open_item_menu"
        android:title="Open"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/delete_item_menu"
        android:title="close"
        />
</menu>

Answer (score 0):

```
//----------------------- Try It ------------------------  
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu

        return true;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.sample.app.MainActivity">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home_white"
            android:orderInCategory="101"
            android:title="Home"
            android:visible="false"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    </menu>
```